# how to parse a non-static nested member to Json?

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson

I have a `JSON` like this:

```
{
    path: {
        : false
        costs: {
            DistanceChecker: 3
        } penalties: {

        }
    },
{
    path: {
        useHovLane: false,
        costs: {
            DistanceChecker: 1,
PenaltyCostChecker: 2
            } penalties: {
                MoreSegmentsPenalty: 2
            }

    }
}
```

Ss you can see `costs` and `penalties` don't always have the same number of nested members.

How can I parse them to JSON?

Here is my code, but it fails as `costs` cannot be parsed to String automatically.

How would you suggest for me to do so, if possible at all?

```
@Override
public CompleteRoutingResponse parseToDto(String entity) throws IOException {
    CompleteRoutingResponse routingResponse = mapper.readValue(entity, CompleteRoutingResponse.class);
}
```

Comment: Hm, doesn't look like a valid json

Answer (score 0):

In general, to be able to parse this input string by JSON, this would need to have it's structure correct as per JSON. Would you mind checking with upstream system to send you correctly formed JSON data.